# cannot make ssh connection from one ubuntu VM to another using ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible, openssh

I have added the host ip address to the file /etc/ansible/hosts of client VM
And then used following 2 commands:

1st is to make ssh connection
ansible all -m ping

2nd is to execute something on the host
ansible all -a "/bin/echo hello"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like your question isn't about programming which is the topic of this site. Can you please ask this question in, for instance, Server Fault and add error messages or issue description?

Comment: Hi...WC to SO!Kindly go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - this link will help you to understand the type of question to be asked in SO!. The question you have asked is quite at the initial level and involves understanding ansible more. You can refer a guide/tutorial for the same.